# Data source to equal input box value

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, case

I have an Excel file that updates my Access database, however I realised the Access database regularly changes location so I would like the file location to be inputted by an input box and this used. I've tried case select but this hasn't been successful, here's what I have so far:

```
d = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter file path", Title:="Please enter the file path", Default:="File Location")
Select Case StrPtr(d)
Case 0

Exit Sub
Case Else
Dim cnn As Object
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngID As Long, LR As Long, Upd As Long
Dim strID As String

LR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Update").Range("BN" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Upd = LR - 1
lngRow = 2

Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
"Data Source=d"
```

Comment: Could try a native file dialogue window http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s209/type-filedialog.htm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915179/ms-access-browse-for-file-and-get-file-name-and-path

Comment: Yep, agree, file dialogue might be better. In any event change last line to `..."Data Source=" & d`

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll have a look in to file dialogue!

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to use the FileDialog, because it is better at preventing invalid input. However, if you want to just use an input box, you can use the `Dir` function to validate that it resolves to an existing file path.

```
d = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter file path", Title:="Please enter the file path", Default:="File Location")
If Dir(d) = vbNullString
    'This is not a valid path, you might want to show a messagebox.
    Exit Sub
End If
```