# How to remove Run-time error '3464' when stopping code with a cancellation request

Tags: vba, ms-access, error-handling, runtime, cancellation

I have a small problem with my code (MS Access VBA). It's not a big deal, but it's not something that should be seen with a cancellation request.

The initial part of the code allows me to extract the path and filename of an image which works beautifully.

```
Private Sub Image2_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

'Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915179/ms-access-browse-for-file-and-get-file-name-and-path

    Dim f As Object
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim varItem As Variant

    Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
    f.AllowMultiSelect = False
    If f.Show Then
        For Each varItem In f.SelectedItems
            strFile = Dir(varItem)
            strFolder = Left(varItem, Len(varItem) - Len(strFile))
            TempVars.Add "imagePath2", strFolder & strFile

       Next
    End If
    Set f = Nothing
```

The next portion inserts that string into the specified field in my query. This also works beautifully.

```
With DoCmd
    .SetWarnings False
    .OpenQuery "updateQueryVarietiesImage2"
    .SetWarnings True
     DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRefresh
     Me.Requery

End With

End Sub
```

The problem I am having is if I cancel selecting the image from the generated pop-up window. After cancelling I get "Run-time error '3464': Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

Clicking on "Debug" highlights

```
.OpenQuery "updateQueryVarietiesImage2"
```

I'm sure the error has to do with the fact that the query didn't run due to the cancellation, but I don't want the error to show up. What code should I be using to stop the error from coming up if the user hits Cancel?

Comment: Answer would depend on the language, which you have failed to specify.

Comment: Sorry, VBA in MS Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just skip the code if no file is selected:

```
If f.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
    With DoCmd
        .SetWarnings False
        .OpenQuery "updateQueryVarietiesImage2"
        .SetWarnings True
        .RunCommand acCmdRefresh
    End With
    Me.Requery        
End If
```

Comment: Perfect!....Well almost perfect. I was still getting an error after replacing my code with yours but I quickly found out I just had to remove

    "Set f = Nothing"

from the first portion and your code worked perfectly.  FYI removing

    "Set f = Nothing"

from my initial code still produced the error so it was your code that did the trick.

Comment: Great. Then please mark as answered. Happy New Year!